# Why is no article used in this sentence?

Tags: articles, zero-article

I read  the following sentence on Twitter:

> Today, a dream comes true. **Koeman was part of the Dream Team Cruyff built.** After the recent history of great managers, Koeman is here to continue that.

Why didn't the author use an article with **part** here? I believe **part** is a countable noun.

> Koeman was **a** part of the Dream Team Cruyff built

Comment: Of related interest at EL&U: *[“As part of” versus “as a part of”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13711)* and *[Should I use an article with the word “part”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87713)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Part" is more often used without an article than with one. In fact, if you looked it up in the dictionary you would see that most of the examples are without.

These are the top examples from the [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/part) definition of "part":

- Part of my steak isn't cooked properly.
- Part of this form seems to be missing.
- Exercise has become part of my daily routine.

Yes, "parts" can be countable (eg "there are six parts to this television series"), but it is also used in a similar way to a determiner - for example, you could say you ate "*some of* the cake" or "*part of* the cake".

Notice that all these examples, including yours, refer to *part of* something else, and all those things have an article or a determiner. "Part" can be used as a noun in isolation to refer to a *component* of something, such as a vehicle part. This usage is normally used with an article, for example, "*I've ordered a part for my car*".